# Does anyone know how to eliminate creation of stdout.txt and stderr.txt when SDL program is executed

Tags: c++, sdl

There is some information about this in SDL FAQ but what I need is to completely eliminate these files, not redirect the output to console. I want the program to only create them if there was any output, although even that is not necessary. The files are just a nuisance and I just want to get rid of them.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/FAQ_Windows_Where_stdout_/_stderr

Comment: I read this article. It mentions that there is an option of not using SDLmain at all. How exactly do I accomplish that? I am not concerned about portability issues yet. Another option that it suggests is to recompile SDL which seems a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

direct the output of both to NUL.

Comment: I tried
     std::cout.rdbuf (NULL);
and
     std::cout.setstate(std::ios::failbit);

The files are still being created

Comment: Bit of a hack - but after SDL_init() you could `unlink` "stdout.txt" and "stderr.txt".

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but I thought unlink is a posix system call, I don't think this will work under windows.

Comment: Quite right sorry - I had my nix hat on. I meant the windows equivalent of unlink.

Comment: I'm not sure Windows allows unlinking files while they are still in use.

Answer (score 0):

## How to use your own `main`

You could avoid using the `main` which comes with SDL, and provide your own `main` instead. According to [this mail](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.sdl/51476) you will be able to accomplish this in SDL 1.3 by defining a macro called `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` before including `SDL.h`. [The commit for this](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/e4add1082c2e) changed `SDL_main.h` only, so you might be able to patch that file in your local SDL install without having to recompile anything. But as the main effect appears to be avoiding a definition of `main` as a preprocessor macro, it might be possible to simply to this:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#undefine main
```

Untested, though. You might have to trick your build system in not using the library which provides `main` resp. `WinMain` for SDL.

Seeing as [`SDL_main.h`](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/f14cf9d71233/include/SDL_main.h) does not the above code does not define `WinMain` as a macro, you might simply be able to declare your own `WinMain` function without doing any preprocessor tricks. Again you might or might not have to omit one library, so try this out.

## State of affairs in 1.3

Note that in SDL 1.3 you won't have to worry about these files any more: it will also include [this commit](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/ed4d4f1ea201) which, among others

> - Pulled the stdio redirection from WinMain()

So this gives you another set of options, if you are willing to compile SDL from source: you could start using SDL from the current HG tree, although doing so might expose you to possibly unstable implementations. Or you could port that single commit back to SDL 1.2, as compatibility with future versions should suffer no ill effects from doing so.